# Failed to compile: Module not found: Can't resolve in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, reference

I was about rounding up this activity and I started getting this error:

***Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Post' in ./src/pages/index.js***

I have tried all I could but was not able to solve this problem. Below is the list of my codes:

**index.js**

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import Posts from './components/Pagination';
    import Pagination from './components/Post';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const Home = () => {
      const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
      const [postsPerPage] = useState(10);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
          setPosts(res.data);
          setLoading(false);
        };
    
        fetchPosts();
      }, []);
      // Get current posts
      const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
      const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
      const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
    
      // Change page
      const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            height: '90vh'
          }}
        >
          <img src={require('../images/top_img.jpg')} alt='logo' height='500px' width='100%'/>
          <div className='container mt-5'>
          <h1 className='text-primary mb-3'>LATEST NEWS</h1>
          <Posts posts={currentPosts} loading={loading} />
          <Pagination
            postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
            totalPosts={posts.length}
            paginate={paginate}
          />
        </div>
        </div>
    
      );
    };
    
    export default Home;
```

**Post.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    const Posts = ({ posts, loading }) => {
      if (loading) {
        return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
      }
    
      return (
        <ul className='list-group mb-4'>
          {posts.map(post => (
            <li key={post.id} className='list-group-item'>
              {post.title}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    };
    
    export default Posts;
```

**Pagination.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    const Posts = ({ posts, loading }) => {
      if (loading) {
        return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
      }
    
      return (
        <ul className='list-group mb-4'>
          {posts.map(post => (
            <li key={post.id} className='list-group-item'>
              {post.title}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    };
    
    export default Posts;
```

Below is the structure of my code:

[image: The structure of my code]

Comment: you swapped your component names in your imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your object names are swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there an error of relative path?

```
    import Posts from '../components/Pagination';
    import Pagination from './components/Post';
```

both imports are in the same file and both files are in the same folder, but one has `../` and other `./`

Comment: I tried both  import Posts from ` '../components/Pagination';,  import Pagination from '../components/Post'; ` and   `import Posts from './components/Pagination'; import Pagination from './components/Post';. Both did not work` .

Comment: @AbubakarOluyinka you pasted the same piece of code in ```Post.js``` and ```Pagination.js``` can you edit and put the correct code in ```Pagination.js``` maybe the problem is there! Another thing, you swapped the objects imported too. Change to this `import Pagination from '../components/Pagination';` `import Post from './components/Post';`

Answer (score 0):

First, you I would make the named imports match the file structure:

```
import Post from "./components/Post"
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination"
```

Also, your default exports are messing things up as well. You will want to export Pagination and then in ./Post you want to export Post.

Lastly, your paths were messed up. The "components" folder is on the same level as index.js. Thus, you can access it through "./components"